Delphi Zlib: how to compress with windowbits -15 (raw deflate)
I need to compress data in a "raw deflate" manner, with Windowbits set to -15. Files containing compressed data have been compressed that way by an external party, which gets decompressed also by an external tool.
To properly decompress this data I have to use windowbits -15. This code works:
procedure DeCompressStreamBits(Src: TMemoryStream; bits: Integer);
Var z: TZDeCompressionStream;
    mem: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Src.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  z := TZDecompressionStream.Create(Src, bits);
  mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
  z.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  mem.CopyFrom(z, z.Size);
  mem.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  Src.Clear;
  Src.SetSize(mem.Size);
  Src.Write(mem.Memory^, mem.Size);
  mem.Free;
  z.Free;
end;

The problem: I need to generate similarly compressed files for that tool to decompress them; what is the correct way to do that in this case? the following code results in the destination stream being empty.
procedure CompressStreamBits(Src: TMemoryStream; bits: Integer);
Var z: TZCompressionStream;
    mem: TMemoryStream;
begin
  mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
  z := TZCompressionStream.Create(mem, zcFastest, bits);
  Src.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  z.CopyFrom(Src, Src.Size);
  mem.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  Src.Clear;
  Src.SetSize(mem.Size);
  Src.Write(mem.Memory^, mem.Size);
  mem.Free;
  z.Free;
end;


On a side note: your Creates and Frees should be protected with try..finally

There is a ZlibEx library that has a great functions ZCompressStream2 and ZDecompressStream2 that do exactly what you need.

Found the problem, with this Zlib implementation you have to free the compression stream first to flush the data into the destination.
Fixed code:
procedure CompressStreamBits(Src: TMemoryStream; bits: Integer);
Var z: TZCompressionStream;
    mem: TMemoryStream;
begin
  mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
  z := TZCompressionStream.Create(mem, zcFastest, bits);
  Src.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  z.CopyFrom(Src, Src.Size);
  z.Free; // must free it so data is flushed to the stream
  mem.Seek32(0, soBeginning);
  Src.Clear;
  Src.SetSize(mem.Size);
  Src.Write(mem.Memory^, mem.Size);
  mem.Free;
end;


Not familiar with Delphi. But do you not have a windowBits argument somewhere?  zlib has a deflateInit2() advanced function that lets you pass that -15. There might be a similar for Delphi.
If that interface is not available, try compressing as a ZLIB formatted buffer RFC1950.  Then throw away the ZLIB header (the first 2 bytes) and the checksum (the last 4 bytes.)  The ZLIB header should start with 0x78 according to the List_of_file_signatures wikipedia. You might also try compressing as a gzip buffer (RFC9152) but stripping out the header requires more work.

It does, I'm passing the -15 to the corresponding function: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.ZLib.TZCompressionStream
It may be a bug in their implementation of the zlib

I see it in the doc.  The 3rd argument of Create() should accept -15 but apparently not.  "Values between 8 and 15 set the buffer size, negative values indicate the raw processing,"
